# Pop UITableViewCell subview over entire screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a tableView, with a `UIWebView` in each row.

When the webView is tapped, I'd like for it to just expand and take over the entire screen.

However, there a few problems, and I'm not sure which is interfering. First I tried something like this:

```
webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
webview.bounds = self.view.bounds;
cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
webView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

However, the webView seems to have trouble overtaking the cell, doesn't expand to proper width and generally doesn't work. I also thought about manipulating the cell height, but it seems to be more trouble than it should be.

So basically, I'd like to move this webView to the top of the stack and change its frame size.

Otherwise I may just instantiate a new webView which seems like a waste. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the frame of the web view. Have the web view tied to all four sides of the cell using constraints (or at least the top and bottom), and when you tap on the cell, and it gets selected, use the indexPathForSelectedRow property in heightForRowAtIndexPath to make that cell as big as the table view.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return tableView.frame.size.height;
    }else{
        return 44;
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would put a WebView in a cell.. I'm no expert but wouldn't the webview be recreated everytime you scroll?

You could use [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController) and place the following code in your didselectrowatindexpath to present it modally.

```
SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://google.com"];
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```